# recurring payments where i can pass in the amount and number of payments

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I am trying to make a recurring payment button but I want to be able to pass to it the total amount to pay and the amount of payments

if i create a button in paypal then i have to create a button for every option - is there anyway to pass in the html the amount and the number of payments

Answer (score 0):

When creating your button makes sure to disable the "save at PayPal" option which turns it into a hosted button.  This will make all of the button details available in the HTML code.

At that point you could then dynamically set the values of the HTML form parameters.

Keep in mind that doing this is less secure because somebody could view source, copy your button code, adjust the values to whatever they want, and then check out that way.

The best way to do this would be using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/), but that will require more coding knowledge.

Comment: thanks for your help but it still gives me encrypted code

Comment: Encrypted code or just not many parameters?  You could be setting up an encrypted button, which is different from a hosted button.  Need to make sure it's neither encrypted nor hosted.

Comment: thanks but where do i see the settings for encrypted

Comment: I don't see any option not to do encrypted - when i chose to disable save to paypal it encrypted and I don't see any other options though i'm looking